# Minecraft OnGround Tag Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to test for a gold block that is on the ground. I want to use the on ground tag because if I don't, it detects the item immediately after I throw it. The command that I'm using doesn't seem to work, and says `The dataTag does not match for 567f4056-607b-4382-9d08-ed6ffa91fdfb`. However when I remove the `{OnGround:1b}` from the command, it works.

Here is the command:
`scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] MINE 1 {OnGround:1b,Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_block",tag:{display:{Name:"Gold Mine",Lore:["Drop To Spawn A Mine"]}}}}`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Already fixed. For some reason minecraft:gold_block wasn't working, so i retyped it and it worked!

Comment: You can write that as your own answer to this and accept it, then this doesn't remain an open question that people try to solve.

Comment: @Cobalt772 You should post that as an answer so future reads can more easily see what solved your problem